# How to use Tags from Body in WebFluxTagsProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-micrometer

I am attempting to get an element from my body as a tag to the `http.requests` metrics.
I attempted to use the `WebFluxTagProvider` but it wants an `Iterable<Tag>` when the information is coming from the ServerWebExchange request body which is a `Flux<DataBuffer>`

Here is the code I tried

```java
import example.companyname.dto.Log;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tag;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebFluxTagsProvider;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;

@Component
public class ApplicationIdTagProvider extends DefaultWebFluxTagsProvider {

  private final Jackson2JsonDecoder jsonDecoder;

  public ApplicationIdTagProvider(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.jsonDecoder = new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper);
  }

  @Override
  public Iterable<Tag> httpRequestTags(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    var tag = exchange.getRequest()
        .getBody()
        .map(dataBuffer ->
          (Log) jsonDecoder.decode(dataBuffer, forClass(Log.class), null, null)
        )
        .log()
        .map(log -> Tag.of("applicationId", log.getApplicationId()))
        .collectList()
        .share()
        .block();

    return tag;
  }
}
```

This code "works" as in it compiles and run but the List when passed through with the debugger is empty (and so is the result).

This leads me to my two questions:

- Is this the correct way to approach the issue?
- How can I make this work?

  - The `Iterable<Tag>` leads me to believe that I am forced to pass through blocking code, which I don't seem to be able to do which `Flux<DataBuffer>`

Update 8th of April 2021:

- I keep looking into it and I am pretty sure it's not possible to do with non-blocking code. I am not sure it's possible to do what we want at all. The documentation is pretty scarce on this feature.

Update 20th of April 2021:

- I didn't find a satisfactory solution, we were not really fan of parsing the body twice either, we consequently renounced to do this.